# Behaviour of volatile keyword c++

Tags: c++, pointers, volatile

What effect does volatile have on pointers?
I got some unexpected behavior while using it

```
int main() {

volatile uint32_t *ptr=((uint32_t *)(0x00000000+0x00100100));
cout<<ptr<<endl;

uint32_t *ptr1=((uint32_t *)(0x00000000+0x00100100));
cout<<ptr1<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

"ptr" returns value 1, while 
"ptr1" return value 0x100100.

What causes this difference?

Comment: What are they pointing to?

Comment: It does have an effect on the display of the variable. Doesn't matter what they point to, as we just display the address here, not the pointee.

Comment: My guess: Different overloads of `operator<<` are selected. The first one is probably the one for booleans.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I was just checking the working of the keyword Volatile,gave random addresses,even If I change the address the "volatile uint32_t *ptr=((uint32_t *)(0x00000000+0x00100100)" still gives output as 1